# Bison shift reduce conflict on comma

Tags: parsing, bison, lalr

I have strange shift-reduce warnings no matter what I change. Reduced grammar:

```
expr : NUMBER 
     | NUMBER ',' expr 
     | expr ',' NUMBER ',' NUMBER
```

Bison reports  shift reduce on 2nd rule with comma. I tried to set precedence:

```
%nonassoc num_p
%nonassoc exp_p

expr : NUMBER %prec num_p
     | NUMBER ',' expr %prec exp_p 
     | expr ',' NUMBER ',' NUMBER
```

but warning stays the same. Can someone explain me what am I missing here?

Comment: That is not enough information. You need to at least show the productions which participate in the conflict.

Comment: @rici there are 500+ rules. I wrote only the ones that has to do with above non-terminals. So:
`expr : NUMBER
     | NUMBER ',' expr
     | expr ',' NUMBER ',' NUMBER`

Comment: That is very different from your question or your earlier comment. If it is really part of your grammar, then it is the cause of the conflict. I suggest that you edit your question, so that it can be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that the following is ambiguous:

```
expr : NUMBER %prec num_p
     | NUMBER ',' expr %prec exp_p 
     | expr ',' NUMBER ',' NUMBER
```

since any list of three or more numbers can be parsed in various ways. Roughly speaking, we can take single numbers off the beginning of the list or pairs of numbers off the end of the list, until we meet somewhere in the middle; however, there is no definition of where the middle point might be.

Consider, for example, the various parse trees which could produce `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Here are just two (with numbers indicating which production was used to expand `expr`):

```
    expr(2)                       expr(3)
    /    \                       /   |  \
  /       \                     /    |   |  
 |    expr(2)                  /     |   |  
 |     /   \                  /      |   |
 |    /     \             expr(3)    |   |
 |   /    expr(3)          / | \     |   |
 |   |    /  | \          /  |  \    |   |
 |   |expr(1)|  \     expr(1)|   |   |   |
 |   |   |   |   |       |   |   |   |   |
 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5       1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5
```

Both of the above trees are, in some sense, maximal. The one on the left takes as many single NUMBERs as possible using production 2, until only two NUMBERs are left for production 3. The one on the right applies production 3 as many times as possible. (It would have needed a single application of production 2 if the list of numbers had an even length.)

In order to resolve the ambiguity, we need a clear statement of the intent. But it seems to me unlikely that it can be resolved with a precedence declaration. Remember that precedence relations are always between a *possible reduction* (on the top of the parser stack) and a *lookahead symbol*. They never compare two lookahead symbols nor two productions. If the lookahead symbol wins, it is shifted onto the stack; if the reduction wins, the stack is reduced. It is no more complicated than that.

So if precedence could help, the relevant token must be `','`, not `NUMBER`. `NUMBER` must always be shifted onto the parse stack. Since no production ends with `','`, it is never possible to reduce the stack when `NUMBER` is the lookahead symbol. By contrast, when `','` is the lookahead symbol, it is usually possible either to reduce the top of the parser stack or to shift the `','` in preparation for a different reduction.

The only place where this decision is even possible is in the case where we have seen `NUMBER` and are looking at a `','`, so we have to decide whether to apply production 1, in preparation for production 3, or shift the `','`, leaving production 2 as the only option. Neither of these decisions can prosper: If we choose to reduce, it is possible that production 3 will turn out to be impossible because there are not enough numbers in the list; if we choose to shift, then production 3 will never be used.

In a left-to-right parse, the algorithm which produces the right-hand parse above is not possible, because we cannot know whether the list is of even or odd length until we reach the end, at which point it is far too late to retroactively reduce the first two numbers. On the other hand, the left-hand parse will require a lookahead of four tokens, not one, in order to decide at which point to stop using production 2. That makes it possible to construct an LR(1) grammar, because there is a way to rewrite any LR(k) grammar as an LR(1) grammar, but the resulting grammar is usually complicated.

I suspect that neither of these was really your intention. In order to recommend a resolution, it will be necessary to know what the precise intention is.

One possibility (motivated by a comment) is that `expr` also includes something which is neither a number nor a list of numbers:

```
expr: NUMBER
    | complex_expression
```

In that case, it might be that the grammar intends to capture two possibilities:

- a list containing `NUMBER`s with a possibly `complex_expression` at the end;
- a list containing an even number of `NUMBER`s with a possibly `complex_expression` at the beginning.

What is left ambiguous in the above formulation is a list consisting only of `NUMBER`s, since either the first or last number could be parsed as an `expr`. Here there are only a couple of reasonable possible resolutions:

- a list of `NUMBER`s is always be parsed as the first option (`expr` at the end)
- a list of `NUMBER`s is parsed as the second option (`expr` at the beginning) if and only if there are an odd number of elements in the list.

The first resolution is much easier, so we can start with it. In this case, the first element in the list essentially determines how the list will be parsed, so it not possible to reduce the *first* `NUMBER` to `expr`. We can express that by separating the different types of `expr`:

```
expr: list_starting_expr | list_ending_expr
list_starting_expr: complex_expression ',' NUMBER ',' NUMBER
                  | list_start_expr ',' NUMBER ',' NUMBER
list_ending_expr  : complex_expression
                  | NUMBER ',' list_ending_expr 
                  | NUMBER
```

The last production in the above example allows for a list entirely of `NUMBER`s to be parsed as a `list_ending_expr`.

It also allows a list containing only a single `complex_expression` to be parsed as a `list_ending_expr`, while a `list_starting_expr` is required to have at least three elements. Without that, a list consisting only of a `complex_expression` would have been ambiguous. In the example grammar in the question, the list containing only a `complex_expression` is implicitly forbidden; that could be reproduced by changing the base production for `list_ending_expr` from `list_ending_expr: complex_expression` to `list_ending_expr: NUMBER ',' complex_expression`.

But what if we wanted the second resolution? We can still recognize the language, but constructing a correct parse tree may require some surgery. We can start by separating out the case where the list consists only of `NUMBER`s.

```
expr: list_starting_expr | list_ending_expr | ambiguous_list
list_starting_expr: complex_expression ',' NUMBER ',' NUMBER
                  | list_starting_expr ',' NUMBER ',' NUMBER
list_ending_expr  : NUMBER ',' complex_expression
                  | NUMBER ',' list_ending_expr 
ambiguous_list    : NUMBER
                  | NUMBER ',' ambiguous_list
```

Despite the frequently-repeated claim that right-recursion should be avoided in bottom-up grammars, here it is essential that `ambiguous_list` and `list_ending_expr` be right-recursive, because we cannot distinguish between the two possibilities until we reach the end of the list.

Now we could use a semantic action to simply count the number of elements in the list. That action needs to be associated with the reduction of `ambiguous_list` to `expr`:

```
expr: list_starting_expr | list_ending_expr
    | ambiguous_list {
        if (count_elements($1) % 2 == 1) {
          $$ = make_list_starting_expr($1);
        }
        else {
          $$ = make_list_starting_expr($1);
        }
      }
```

But we can actually distinguish the two cases grammatically, precisely because of the right recursion:

```
expr: list_starting_expr
    | list_ending_expr
    | even_list_of_numbers
    | odd_list_of_numbers
list_starting_expr  : complex_expression ',' NUMBER ',' NUMBER
                    | list_starting_expr ',' NUMBER ',' NUMBER
list_ending_expr    : NUMBER ',' complex_expression
                    | NUMBER ',' list_ending_expr 
odd_list_of_numbers : NUMBER
                    | NUMBER ',' NUMBER ',' odd_list_of_numbers
even_list_of_numbers: NUMBER ',' NUMBER 
                    | NUMBER ',' NUMBER ',' even_list_of_numbers
```

It might be more meaningful to write this as:

```
expr: expr_type_one | expr_type_two
expr_type_one: list_starting_expr | even_list_of_numbers
expr_type_two: list_ending_expr | odd_list_of_numbers
 /* Remainder as above */
```

***Note:*** The above grammars, like the grammar in the original question, do not allow `expr` to consist only of a `complex_expression`. If that it were desired to handle the case of only a single `complex_expression`, then that syntax could be added directly to the productions for `expr` (or to whichever of `expr_type_one` or `expr_type_two` were appropriate.

Comment: The exact grammar without other rules is:
`expr : SYMBOL ',' NUMBER
     | FUNC1 '(' expr ',' NUMBER ')'
     | FUNC2 '(' NUMBER ',' expr ')'
     | FUNC2 '(' expr ',' NUMBER ',' NUMBER ')'
     | NUMBER`

Comment: @MilošLjumović: It is very difficult to formulate an answer based on shifting sands. You need to ask specific questions with enough details that answers can be given. If you can't see the difference between the three versions of your grammar which you have offered, you need to read more about context-free grammars. Using your comment as a hint, I've tried to provide a general answer which might guide other readers. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score -2):

Sometime it helps to rewrite left recursion to right one, something like this:

```
expr : NUMBER
     | expr ',' NUMBER
     ;
```

Theoretic ground can be found there: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9963/why-is-left-recursion-bad

Comment: Yes @Dewfy, but the thing is that it must be like this because my boss asked to be like that.

Comment: There are lots of good reasons to use left recursion with bottom-up parsers, but avoiding shift/reduce conflicts isn't one of them. In fact, sometimes you need right-recursion to avoid a conflict.